# my Minecraft /tp command thinks there are "no entities" on my team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having a problem with command blocks and teams. I am using Minecraft 1.13.2 and I am on my own public server.
I have a command block that puts me on a team "player". (player is the *actual* name, not just the display name). This team is displayed on the sidebar, so I *know* that I am on the team. However, I run the command:

```
tp @a[team=player] 871 101 876
```

and I get:

> no entity was found

Any ideas?

Comment: The team is on the sidebar? Do you mean a scoreboard? If yes, then people appear on it independent of their team.

Comment: @FabianRöling I added a scoreboard objective called 'player' and then added myself to the objective 'player'. I displayed the objective 'player' as the option " sidebar', making itself visible one I was on it with 0 points. It showed a sidebar with 'points' at the top and my name listed with my 0 points next to it. Sorry if this isn't any help I'm not great at commands in Minecraft. _Quick sidenote, i have noticed that my server, which I run on my PC, doesn't recognise me as a player, as a friend noticed it said 2/20 players, even though it was me and 2 friends in the server_

Comment: That's not a team, it's just a scoreboard objective; they're different things that are still related.  You should probably edit your question to include all the commands you're using.

Comment: Just because a sidebar is only visible to one team doesn't mean that only players of that team are on it.